# Getting simple web project running with Fabric React

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, reactjs, visual-studio-2017, office-ui-fabric

**----UPDATE----**

Got it to work using the following:

- Webpack
- Typescript
- ts-loader
- react
- react-dom
- @types/react
- @types/react-dom
- office-ui-fabric-react

Once I had a simple react example running, it was easy to do the same for fabric-react.

Some good tutorials:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html
- https://medium.com/@gmonne/simple-app-layout-with-office-ui-fabric-react-2eac6361e1b4

---

**----Original post----**

As a newcomer to `React` / `node` I want to create a test application in `Visual Studio 2017` using `Fabric React` (Fabric since I want to adopt the Office look and feel). 
By now I've spent countless of hours figuring out how to get this to work, and encountering problem after problem (e.g. creating `package.json`, installing `Gulp`, etc.) 
There are many tutorials on this topic but all of them seem to be a bit scattered or just on 1 of the dependencies.

**To start with:**

- I want to build a web application - very simple / basic, for test purposes, and just use some of the Fabric UI components.
- I am creating this web project in Visual Studio 2017 as a ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)
- My Visual Studio 2017 version is: Community 2017, version 15.2 (26430.13)
- Using Fabric-React (and not FabricJS)
- Using it with Gulp as suggested at http://dev.office.com/fabric#/get-started

**Up till now I have used the following documentation:**

- https://dev.office.com/fabric#react
- http://dev.office.com/fabric#Overview
- https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md
- http://leruplund.dk/2017/04/15/setting-up-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-with-npm-webpack-and-typescript-part-i/
- [What is the correct way to set up gulp in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188670/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-up-gulp-in-visual-studio-2017)
- https://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp

And probably some more that I forgot..

**The steps done:**

1. Installed `Node` (v6.11.2)
2. Created my web project called Test2
3. Added `npm` (v3.10.10) to my project using the Nuget Package installer
4. Created the `package.json` file. Not sure anymore, after 100 tests, if I did this manually using `npm init` or this was done automatically with installing npm in my project, anyway it is in my project:

[image]

5. Installed `gulp` (using this link [What is the correct way to set up gulp in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188670/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-up-gulp-in-visual-studio-2017)), short summary, I converted my bundleconfig.json file to Gulp using the Bundler & Minifier extension.
6. Tested if `Gulp` ran (and updating package.json) using `Task runner explorer` (worked):
   [image]
7. Installed office-ui-fabric-react as explained here (https://dev.office.com/fabric#react), also installed react and react-dom as explained here (http://dattabase.com/sharepoint-app-fabric-ui-react-part-1-3/)
8. Added a bunch of code to my `site.js` file (which is linked to in my MVC view) - added the command bar react-fabric code listed here: http://dev.office.com/fabric#Variants

This is the part where I am getting stuck. Firstly I am not sure, being unfamiliar with react in general, if I should add the components like this to my view. Secondly, it does not work and give me the following error:

```
site.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Anyone know on which step it went wrong? Some addition info:
**Package.json contains:**

```
{
  "name": "test2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^4.34.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  }
}
```

**site.js contains:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { assign } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Utilities';
import { CommandBar } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/CommandBar';
import { Toggle } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Toggle';

export class CommandBarBasicExample extends React.Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isSearchBoxVisible: true,
            areNamesVisible: true,
            areIconsVisible: true
        };
    }

    public render() {
        let { items, overflowItems, farItems } = this.props;
        let { isSearchBoxVisible: searchBoxVisible, areIconsVisible: iconsVisible, areNamesVisible: namesVisible } = this.state;

        let filteredItems = items.map((item: any) => assign({}, item, {
            name: namesVisible ? item.name : '',
            icon: iconsVisible ? item.icon : ''
        }));

        let filteredOverflowItems = overflowItems.map((item: any) => assign({}, item, {
            name: namesVisible ? item.name : '',
            icon: iconsVisible ? item.icon : ''
        }));

        let filteredFarItems = farItems.map((item: any) => assign({}, item, {
            name: namesVisible ? item.name : '',
            icon: iconsVisible ? item.icon : ''
        }));

        return (
            <div>
                <Toggle
                    label='Show search box'
                    checked={searchBoxVisible}
                    onChanged={isSearchBoxVisible => this.setState({ isSearchBoxVisible })}
                    onText='Visible'
                    offText='Hidden'
                />
                <Toggle
                    label='Show names'
                    checked={namesVisible}
                    onChanged={areNamesVisible => this.setState({ areNamesVisible })}
                    onText='Visible'
                    offText='Hidden' />
                <Toggle
                    label='Show icons'
                    checked={iconsVisible}
                    onChanged={areIconsVisible => this.setState({ areIconsVisible })}
                    onText='Visible'
                    offText='Hidden' />
                <CommandBar
                    isSearchBoxVisible={searchBoxVisible}
                    searchPlaceholderText='Search...'
                    elipisisAriaLabel='More options'
                    items={filteredItems}
                    overflowItems={filteredOverflowItems}
                    farItems={filteredFarItems}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**My project overview:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you're trying to run, is given in [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), but you seem to be running it as a node (JavaScript) application.

Typescript should be installed globally (`npm install typescript -g`). You can then compile `.ts` or `.tsx` from the command-line by typing `tsc site.tsx`. Note that the filetype should be `tsx` for a file containing a JSX template, and it should be `.ts` for a file containing regular TypeScript.

My advice for you is to follow [this excellent example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) on how to create a new React application with TypeScript using Webpack. It's nice to familiarize yourself with Gulp as a task-runner, but Gulp is by no means necessary for React development.

Once you have the example up and running, you can include office-ui-fabric-react and create applications with the components.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found the same tutorial as you mentioned. Besides that I also found some other good sources! I eventually (after some more research) used React in combination with TypeScript, Webpack, TS-Loader, @types/react and react-dom. After getting REACT to run if was fairly easy to get Fabric React running. I am now only strugling with how to adjust the CSS easily.