# ASP.Net MVC project with office ui fabric react

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

We are trying to build a sample application with asp.net MVC using office ui fabric react. Followed the the below steps from node js command prompt as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760238/getting-simple-web-project-running-with-fabric-react).
By following the steps I could get the normal react sample working. I tried to add the fabric UI label code as given below in index.tsx file and then running the application, but fabric react label component is not getting rendered in the browser.
index.tsx code:

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import * as React from 'react';
/* tslint:enable:no-unused-variable */
import { Label } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Label';
export const LabelBasicExample = () => (
    <div>
    <Label>I'm a Label</Label>
    <Label disabled={ true }>I'm a disabled Label</Label>
    <Label required={ true }>I'm a required Label</Label>
    </div>
);
```

After adding this code ran webpack from nodejs command prompt and then tried browsing my index.html which has the below code. But could not see the react component getting rendered and neither I get any error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Hello React!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example"></div>
<!-- Dependencies -->
<script src="./node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<!-- Main -->
<script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help here on is there any additional step that I am missing here or guide me to have the fabric react component working with asp.net.

Thanks

Comment: Please indent your code for better readability.